# How do I change the "Access Denied" message?

Tags: users

I have a need to temporarily unpublish some pages on our website, but when anonymous users try to access an unpublished page, say they had it bookmarked, they get the message:

Access Denied

Which may sound too harsh. I thought about changing it to 'Page Not Found.'

However, I searched the entire site and I can't find any template that controls this particular message. Using Theme Developer, I can see that the Access Denied page is using the standard page.tpl.php, which I don't believe has anything pertaining to the Access Denied page.  What am I missing?

Comment: 'Page Not Found' and 'Access Denied' are two different errors -- 404 and 403, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Drupal 7 & 8, you can set your access denied page and your page not found page easily. Go to `/admin/config/system/site-information` and review the error page section.

Comment: While this is true, it sounds like this posted wanted to swap the message - which is not possible (i.e. show 404 for a 403 for unpublished nodes). It may be technically feasible, but not a great idea.

Comment: If he creates a page, he can set any message he wants to, like 'Page not found'

Comment: Except in the instance when it really isn't a 404, it would be really confusing if say there is an attached user component to this (like an extranet or light Drupal admin access).

Comment: I agree, but I think that's outside of the scope of what the OP is asking. They didn't mention changing the HTTP Response code, just the messaging.

Comment: Actually I just want to soften the message when an unpublished page is being called. I didn't want to change Drupal's functionality, just the change the message to something like "Page not found."  Scott Joudry, thank you so much!

Comment: Just understand that this is a global change, if you are getting 404 in the future while developing or accessing parts of the site, it might be a 403 in disguise.

Comment: lol what?  Its just a message...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7. To find where the string comes from, you can go to your docroot and run `grep -rnw . -e 'You are not authorized to access this page.'` (You might need sudo permission).

I found it inside includes/common.inc at line 2729, under function [drupal_deliver_html_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7.x). That tells me I can try something like [hook_page_delivery_callback_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_delivery_callback_alter/7.x) to modify the output in a custom module.

Comment: You should never modify core, as a general rule.

Comment: I never meant to modify the core, I provided a way to find which hook to use in a custom module...

Comment: `grep` will just find occurrences of the message string - he walked back the response by finding the calling function, which a hook is provided for to alter it before delivery. In fact, there is a comment here that illuminates a possible answer: https://api.drupal.org/comment/54353#comment-54353

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hook_preprocess_page to alter your page. the code example below will help you. add it it to your template.php or custom module.

```
    function Hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
   global $user;       
     if ($vars['title'] == 'Access denied') {


            $normal_path = $_GET['q'];
            $parts=explode('/', $normal_path);
            $nid_part = $parts[1];
            $node = node_load($nid_part);
            if (!isset($node)) {
              return;
            }
            if (($node->status == 0) &&
              ($node->nid == $nid_part) &&
              ($user->uid == 0)) {
              drupal_not_found();
               drupal_exit();
            }
    }
```

simlar question : [check this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156927/how-to-implement-page-not-found-404-for-unpublished-content/203582#203582)

Comment: Hmm... to expand on this, this solution would not work if a node was titled 'Access denied' for whatever reason (short story entry on a site for budding authors, lets say), also, it assumes any authenticated role has unpublished node access. Also, you can get the node object either by `node_load(arg(1))` or by `$node = menu_get_object('node');` without looking at the raw GET parameters.

Comment: true that.  well assuming that no one would create a node that is titled as 'Access Denied' in  the website. you can use this code. alter it to your preferences. `node->status=0` is to check if it's unpublished. 

by default Drupal will give 'Access denied' page for unpublished pages.